# How to add constraints such that my UI looks similar on all devices

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, constraints

I can't figure out how to add constraints to my view controller such that it looks correct on all iPhone devices. Below is how my scene should look for example on the iPhone X. I want to add constraints such that the layout looks the same on all devices, and devices that don't have enough height for the same layout will sacrifice height in the "Summary" text view. That is, how can I make the "Summary" text view have a dynamic height so that is scales depending on the size of the device in order to fit the rest of the elements on the screen?

Whenever I add constraints to my ui elements using the pin feature, I always get the following errors for nearly all my elements:

Need constraints for x position or width

Need constraints for y position or height

I'm a bit unfamiliar with constraints but I never seemed to have this problem in the past. Why is using the pin feature and adding the 4 directional constraints for each of my items not sufficient?

For example, if I use the pin feature on my Summary text view and add a 16 point constraint on all sides, it will give me the error that I now need to add constraints to my UIImageView underneath it. If I add constraints for that, and then I repeat this process for all of my elements, I then get the errors above, to which if I try to add height/width constraints, it no longer looks the same on all devices.

[image]

[image]

Edit: above are the constraints for my textview, which still doesn't seem to be adapting to the screen height and instead staying a constant height regardless of device

Comment: Add view to View Controller. Set background colour teal. Add UIView, set background to white and constraint to bottom, left, right. Add sibling UITextView and constraint to left, right, top. Add stackview to bottom white view with 4 circle views in horizontal equal spacing distribution. Constraint it left, right, bottom. Add UIImage view and constrain left, right, top, bottom (to stackview). Add aspect ratio constraint to UIImageView. Constraint textView bottom to UIImageView top. Add height constraint to textView >= 0 and priority hugging high with compress resistance low.

Comment: @Brandon It still seems to be asking for Y/height constraints for the textview, imageview, and stackview

Comment: No.. I just did it: https://imgur.com/a/Rbfzk I did not specify any heights except the height of the circles which I assumed should be fixed size or at least aspect ratio.. I made contentHugging on the textView required and the content compression resistance of it to low so that everything will size how they want and the textview will shrink when necessary..

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for sticking with me I appreciate it, I seemed to get everything else working alright but my textiview still wont adapt its height depending on device. I edited my answer with a screenshot of the textview constraints

Comment: Actually, I put priority low for the bottom constraint on the imageview and this seemed to do the trick, before it was on priority required.